# How to calculate difference between two datetime value in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I wanted to calculate the difference between two date time value in python 3. Both values are in following format :

Date 1 :

```
Wed Jun 24 14:13:48 UTC 2020
```

Date 2 :

```
Thu Jun 25 12:13:48 UTC 2020
```

I wanted to calculate difference between these two dates and verify if the difference is equal to some particular minutes (say 240 min).

I am not able to figure out the code or approach for this scenario in python 3.

Any help is appreciable :)

Comment: post your attempts so we can see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime
date1 = parser.parse('Wed Jun 24 14:13:48 UTC 2020')
date2 = parser.parse('Thu Jun 25 12:13:48 UTC 2020')
diff = date2 - date1
print("Difference[HH:MM:SS]: ", diff)
minutes = diff.seconds / 60
print('Difference in minutes: ', minutes)
```